# Getting distinct results for one property with Grails criteria

Tags: grails, hql, distinct, criteria

From a domain class instance in the database I want to get the last 20 updated records but distinct to a certain property, which in my case is `color`. I've tried 3 different approaches but none seem to work the way I expected.

**First approach:**

`def corridors = TerminKorridor.findAll([max:20, sort:'lastUpdated', order:"desc"]).color.unique();`

works but doesn't return 20 entries

**Second approach:**

```
 def corridors = corridorsCriteria.list{
            distinct("color")
            maxResults(20)
            order("lastUpdated", "desc")
         }
```

doesn't remove entries with same colors. Distinct doesn't work

**Third approach:**

```
def corridors = TerminKorridor.executeQuery("Select distinct a.color from TerminKorridor a order by a.lastUpdated desc",[max:20])
```

doesn't remove entries with same colors, `distinct` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think there is a problem with your logic somewhere here.

The goal is to get a list of 20 distinct colors ordered by lastUpdated.

You cant order by lastUpdated if you want a distinct list. It doesn't make sense. If you have 3 items with the same color, which lastUpdated would you use to do the ordering?

You have to choose if you are getting the last 20 records and then a distinct list of colors, which would almost certainly result in less than 20 records

OR

You get a list of 20 distinct colors

You could do this with some code though.

```
LinkedHashSet<Color> colors = new LinkedHashSet()

try {
    TerminKorridor.findAll([sort:'lastUpdated', order:"desc"]).each {
        if (colors.size() < 20) {
            colors.add(it.color)
        } else {
            throw new GetOutOfHereException()
        }
    }
} catch(GetOutOfHereException e) {
 null
}
```

You could make this better by using HQL to only load the colors instead of the entire objects

```
TerminKorridor.executeQuery("select t.color from TerminKorridor t order by t.lastUpdated desc").each { ... }
```

Comment: Whoa, using an exception for program flow is a big no-no! Check out this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3050218/1110820) for some alternatives, such as returning `true` to break out of the loop.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control for more on why this is a bad idea.