# How to break from groovy 'eachFileMatch()'

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a working script that lists all pdf files in a directory. It's working as desired but all I need is actually the file name of the first pdf file. Then I want to break the `eachFileMatch()` as there could be thousands of pdf files in the directory.

I tried to use `find` from this [Break from groovy each closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049790/break-from-groovy-each-closure) answer after `eachFileMatch().find` but didn't work `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.eachFileMatch() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.regex.Pattern) values: [.*.(?i)pdf]`

```
        def directory="c:\\tmp"   // place 2 or more pdf files in that
                                  // directory and run the script
        def p =  ~/.*.(?i)pdf/
        new File( directory ).eachFileMatch(p) { pdf ->
                println pdf // and break
        }
```

Could anyone give me an idea how to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can not break out of these `each{}` methods (exceptions will work, but that would be really dirty).  if you check the code for `eachFileMatch`, you see, that it already reads the whole `list()` and itereates over it.  so one option here is to just use the regular JDK methods and use `find` to return the first:

```
// only deal with filenames as string
println new File('/tmp').list().find{it=~/.tmp$/}

// work with `File` objects
println new File('/tmp').listFiles().find{it.isFile() && it=~/.tmp$/}
```

Comment: Beauty! Works smoothly. Thanks for the explanation as well for both methods. I needed the second one. Nice to know both.

Comment: You meant it==, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
use 
 ^.*?.(?i)pdf
```

this will give only the first match

Comment: `def p = ^.*?.(?i)pdf ` doesn't work for me. I am getting `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:\createcontrol.txt: 15: unexpected token: ^ @ line 15, column 12.`

Comment: hm, it must be syntax issue. `def p = ^.*?.(?i)pdf` gives me the error. And `def p = /^.*?.(?i)pdf/` gives me empty output.

Comment: @Radek regex should be ~ /regex/ of this form.def p = ~/^.*?.(?i)pdf/

Comment: ok, syntax fixed. Thank you. But it gives me the same result. All pdf files.

Comment: @Radek can you give a sample input

Comment: I updated code sample. Please create c:\tmp directory and place 2 or more pdf files and run the code. Mine reg exp and yours gives me the same result - all pdf files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60496/discussion-between-vks-and-radek).

Comment: i doubt that this can be solved with the regexp, as the regexp is called for each file and does not cary over any state to the next check.