# Groovy println then break from closure

Tags: java, groovy, closures

I have the following simple groovy script that I understand will not work after reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049790/break-from-groovy-each-closure). But  my question now is why does this not exit the closure. Could someone provide an explanation or point my to the docs that discuss closures.Thanks

```
def inputFile = new File("input.txt")
inputFile.eachLine{ it ,i ->
  if(it.contains("abcd")){
    println "abcd found on line: " + i
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's a very good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049790/break-from-groovy-each-closure

Comment: Yea I just read this actually, I am going to edit my question now. I would still like to know why this is the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic pseudo code ran in `eachLine` is:

```
while (true) {
    def line = readLineFromFile()
    if (line==null) {
        break
    }
    closure(line, count++)
}
```

So there is nothing else, than the end of the file, to stop.  Your `return` in the closure works, but it returns just *from* the closure.

For details see the source of [`org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.eachLine`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java#L478).

Closures are not language constructs like `while` or `for`.  They are just passed in anonymous functions with context.  It gets more clear, if you write it out, what the code actually means (no groovy shortcuts): `inputFile.eachLine({it,i->...})` (note the () from the method call here)

In general: `each.*` in groovy does not care for the result of your closure.  A return in the closure just means an early bail out (in your case it's a no-op).

So for the general question, can you `break` from closures?  "No".  Iff your caller works with the result, state, ... of the closure in any way to *allow* you to break from it (e.g. `[].find()` does: iterate the list, until the closure returns true, then return the element), you are not able to (well you can throw an exception).

Answer (score 1):

Groovy's `each*` methods do NOT exit the loop if you do return in it's "body". they simply cancel the execution of this body instance and move on to the next one.

In contrast, "find" method DOES return immediately if the closure returns true.

You can either use the plain looping with `for` or `while`, or (not recommended) let your closure throw some exception