# Closure Return Statement does not exit Method

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

I have the following method places in a grails 2.4.5 Service.

```
   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
   @Transactional
   void addPermission(Company company, String username, Permission permission) {


     if (AclClass.findByClassName(Company.class.name)) {
       def acl = aclUtilService.readAcl(company)
       Sid sidObject = new PrincipalSid(username)

       acl.entries.eachWithIndex { entry, i ->
          println("adddd")
          if (entry.sid.equals(sidObject) && entry.permission.equals(permission)) 
            return
          }
       }
     }
     aclUtilService.addPermission company, username, permission
   }
```

The problem is that the `return` statement in the if block does not quite the method addPermission. It just quits the eachWithIndex closure.

**How can I exit the addPermission function at the place where I put the return statement?**

Comment: That would seem very unsafe if possible. Use a regular loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049790/break-from-groovy-each-closure