# Skip to next loop if matches condition in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm very new to groovy so please excuse if its a silly question.

I'm parsing a XML file and fetching the fruit names to a list. My incomplete code snippet below.

```
....
....
def xmlOutput = proc.in.text
def lists = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlOutput)
def listOffruits = lists.fruits.entry.name

//Below is the fuit list for which I want to skip the loop
def myList = ["orange", "apple", "banana", "grapes"]

listOffruits.each(){
  def fruitName = it.text()
    //Not sure how on the logic
println "- found Fruit Name not on the list'${fruitName }'"
}
```

I want to check/compare if the fruit name is present in the list - "**myList**" , if present skip the loop or move on to next iterator ,if not continue with the loop.

I'm not sure how exactly to achieve it. Any suggestions pls. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049790/break-from-groovy-each-closure

Comment: @Nitesh , Thanks, but i want to compare/check every value of list - listOffruits to the values in the another list - myList .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findAll` to just keep the fruit not in the list...

```
def unfoundFruits = listOffruits.findAll { f -> !myList.contains(f) }
unfoundFruits.each { f ->
    println "- found Fruit Name not on the list '${f}'"
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for introducing me to the findAll method. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collection#minus`, for example:

```
def listOffruits = ["pineapple", "apple", "strawberry", "grapes"]
def myList = ["orange", "apple", "banana", "grapes"]
println "Fruits not on the list: ${listOffruits.minus myList}"
```