# Best way to work on multi-line output from external process called from groovy script?

Tags: groovy, process

I use this method:

```
def runProcess(List cmd) {
  def process = cmd.execute()
  def output = new StringWriter(), error = new StringWriter()
  process.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
  def exitCode = process.exitValue()
  if (exitCode) {
    throw new Exception("Error: $error with code: $exitCode")
  }
  return output.toString().split()
}
```

To run external processes that can return one or multiple lines of output.

Sometimes I need to inspect each line and return a match if found. First I tried with an `eachLine` closure but found that I cannot return from that ([Can you break from a Groovy "each" closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049790/can-you-break-from-a-groovy-each-closure)):

```
def sample() {
  String tagName = ""
  def tags = runProcess(["git", "tag"])
  tags.eachLine { tag -> 
    println "tag $tag"
    if(tag = "mytag") {
      tagName = tag
      // Cannot return from a eachLine closure :-(
      return tag
    }
  }
  return tagName
}
```

The above will work but if I have 1000 lines it will go through all of them - since the return statement is ignored.

I am now trying with a classic `for` loop:

```
def sample() {

  def tags = runProcess(["git", "tag"])
  println "tags.getClass() "  + tags.getClass() // this is java.lang.String
  String[] tagsArr = tags.split("\n");
  println "tags.getClass() "  + tagsArr.getClass() // this is [Ljava.lang.String
     
  if (tagsArr != null && tagsArr.length > 0) { // does NOT = true when tagsArr is empty :-(
     for (String tag : tagsArr) {
        def desc = shellCommand(["git", "describe","--tags","$tag"])
        if(desc.trim() == "mytag") {
          println "Found tag: $tag at HEAD"
          return tag
        }
     }
  }
}
```

This is pretty verbose/ugly and does *not* work when `tagsArr` is *empty* (still investigating this and any input is appreciated!).

Any suggestions on how to implement better handling of multi-lines output from calling an external process?

Also this from above:

```
return output.toString().split()
```

does not seem right...

I have also looked at:

http://konstructcomputers.blogspot.com/2013/12/groovy-line-by-line-process-output.html

which looks quite verbose/extensive. I hoped that groovy offered some minimal way of doing this to avoid this kind of "low level" boilerplate code.

**Sidenote**. Interestingly enough this page:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/working-with-io.html

does not mention `waitForProcessOutput` which I thought was the most robust way to get output from an external process.

**UPDATED Example (with readLines and find)**

Below an update example based on suggestion below. I modified the original example to make it more clear.

**Expected result = annotated**

```
$ git for-each-ref refs/tags
67a27fec636a12346f391c67be01a0c8c0e1b7b8 commit refs/tags/001
67a27fec636a12346f391c67be01a0c8c0e1b7b8 commit refs/tags/002
67a27fec636a12346f391c67be01a0c8c0e1b7b8 commit refs/tags/003
706a21e04441c43e2b0372bd8607be74c0377690 tag    refs/tags/annotated
67a27fec636a12346f391c67be01a0c8c0e1b7b8 commit refs/tags/lightweight
```

**Using find() and split() (working)**

```
def runProcess(List cmd) {
  def process = cmd.execute()
  def outputWriter = new StringWriter(), errorWriter = new StringWriter()
  process.waitForProcessOutput(outputWriter, errorWriter)
  String output = outputWriter.toString()
  String error = errorWriter.toString()
  int exitCode = process.exitValue()
  if (exitCode) {
    throw new Exception("Error: $error exit code: $exitCode")
  }
  // Notice split()
  return output.split()
}

def sample() {
  def tags = runProcess(["git", "tag","--points-at","HEAD"])
  def result = tags.find{tag -> 
    def tagType = runProcess(["git", "cat-file","-t","$tag"])
    if(tagType[0] == "tag") {
      return tag
    }
  }
  return result
}

assert(result == "annotated")
```

**readLines() and find() (also working)**

```
def runProcess(List cmd) {
  def process = cmd.execute()
  def outputWriter = new StringWriter(), errorWriter = new StringWriter()
  process.waitForProcessOutput(outputWriter, errorWriter)
  String output = outputWriter.toString()
  String error = errorWriter.toString()
  int exitCode = process.exitValue()
  if (exitCode) {
    throw new Exception("Error: $error exit code: $exitCode")
  }
  // Notice NO split()
  return output
}

def sample() {
  def tags = runProcess(["git", "tag","--points-at","HEAD"])

  def result = tags.readLines().find{ tag ->
    def tagType = runProcess(["git", "cat-file","-t","$tag"])
    if(tagType.trim()  == "tag") {
      return tag
    }
  }
  return result
}

assert(result == "annotated")
```

Comment: now i can't understand what u r trying to do.  what do you want to get from `git for-each-ref refs/tags` result? `annotated` ?

Comment: Yep but only for tags point to HEAD. But more generally I am trying to understand calling external processed and working on the output in groovy better.

Comment: `split()` without parameters  splits string by spaces. `readLines()` splits string by lines.

Comment: in your case output is just a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String sample() {
  def tags = runProcess(["git", "tag"]) // expected multiline string to be returned
  tags.readLines().find{tag->
    def desc = ...
    return desc=="mytag" // will break on first true returned
  }
}
```

here is a test script you could run in any online console:

```
def tags = '''
aaa
bbb
ccc
'''

def found = tags.readLines().find{tag->
    return "BBB" ==  tag.toUpperCase()
}

println "found: ${found}"
```

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5201583847505920?execute

another example based on updated question:

```
def output = '''
67a27fec636a12346f391c67be01a0c8c0e1b7b8 commit refs/tags/001
67a27fec636a12346f391c67be01a0c8c0e1b7b8 commit refs/tags/002
67a27fec636a12346f391c67be01a0c8c0e1b7b8 commit refs/tags/003
706a21e04441c43e2b0372bd8607be74c0377690 tag    refs/tags/annotated
67a27fec636a12346f391c67be01a0c8c0e1b7b8 commit refs/tags/lightweight
'''

def tagname = output
                .readLines()
                .findAll()             //keep only non-empty lines
                .collect{it.split()}   //split each line by spaces
                .findAll{it[1]=='tag'} //find all items with 'tag'
                .findResult{tag->
                    def result = true        //evaluate something here to find the one
                    if(result)return tag[2]  //search done - return the value
                    else return null         //continue searching
                }
assert tagname=='refs/tags/annotated'
```

Comment: I tried something similar using `find` which seems to be the trick. I could use `find` directly on the process result like: `tags.find { tag -> ...` so I don't thing that call to `readLine` is necessary.

Comment: [readLines()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#readLines()) converts multiline string to an array of single lines. so find will iterate by each line. applying `find` directly to string will iterate it char-by-char even it's a multiline string.

Comment: In my case - the above example - that should already be handled by the call to `split()`. And if I remove that I get:`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.readLines() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
 ` when adding `readLines()` before `find`

Comment: Seems I was missing a trim() when using readLines - see updated example. Not really sure which version I prefer at the moment both are quite messy.